# amazon elasticsearch service ConnectionTimeout

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk, connection-timeout

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es_url = '*****.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'
# es_conn = Elasticsearch(es_url)
es_conn = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_url, 'port': 443, 'use_ssl': True}])
while 1:
    for ....:
        actions.append(....)
        if len(actions) >= 5000:
            helpers.bulk(es_conn, actions)
            actions = []
    helpers.bulk(es_conn, actions)
```

The code above run on an ec2 instance, it often throw the following error:

```
    helpers.bulk(es_conn, actions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 194, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 162, in streaming_bulk
    for result in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions, raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 91, in _process_bulk_chunk
    raise e
ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='search-shinezoneels-pc3ib5rkhuylqynfoz6rph7gh4.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.)
```

At the same time, I run the code on another EMR instance, the error did not happen at all. Bulk speed on ec2 instance is about twice of EMR instance, but often error. How to fix it?

Comment: How is your access policy document for ES?

Comment: the two instance can access the amazon elasticsearch service.

Comment: Was there ever a fix for this? I am seeing the same issue on my Django site?